# Uninstalling VS2008

Tags: uninstallation, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have VS2010 and VS2008.  Decided to uninstall VS2008 and after the process VS2008 Shell remains.  Can I uninstall this or is another software dependent on it?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: If you have the ability to reinstall if you encounter a problem, go ahead and uninstall. I'm thinking Management Studio might use Visual Studio functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [URL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsx/thread/169a777b-b83d-4e92-af54-0a17b8b1a676) that should answer this for you, but the quick answer is you can uninstall the older shell.

Comment: Thank you! 
I thought I expressed my thanks back then.  I hope it's not too late ;)
Cheers!